# "To have " vs "Having " as perfect infinitive and gerund

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, participle-phrases

> Paceman Rubel Hossain was also recalled to the side
>   after an injury-plagued season, as was left-arm spinner
>   Taijul Islam *having* last played an ODI against New
>   Zealand in the World Cup last year. ( this sentence is collected from an Australian cricket website)

I think it could be correct too if I write -

> Paceman Rubel Hossain was also recalled to the side
>   after an injury-plagued season, as was left-arm spinner
>   Taijul Islam *to have* last played an ODI against New
>   Zealand in the World Cup last year.

If both are correct, then what's the problem with  the following sentence of my last post which is wrong according to a commenter?

> Jones is the latest player *having* signed with
>   Barcelona.

Answer (score 1):

No, "to have last played" is not a participial phrase but an infinitive phrase, and it cannot modify a verb phrase, as participle phrase can.

> John, having played 90 minutes without rest, was winded.
>
> John, to have played 90 minutes without rest, was winded.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

John was winded, having played 90 minutes without rest.

John was winded, to have played 90 minutes without rest.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You ask:

> what's the problem with the following sentence of my last post which
>   is wrong according to a commenter?
>
> **Jones is the latest player having signed with Barcelona.**

The correct form is

**Jones is the latest player to have signed with Barcelona.**

So what is the difference between the following sentences?

> John was winded, to have played 90 minutes without
>   rest.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Jones is the latest player to have signed with
>   Barcelona.<sup>grammatical</sup>

The difference lies in the type of adjective phrase.

> Jones is the player to have signed with Barcelona.
>   <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Jones is the {first, latest, third, tenth, only} player to have signed
>   with Barcelona. <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> Jones is the least|most skilled player to have signed with Barcelona.
>   <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> Jones is the skilled player to have signed with Barcelona.
>   <sup>ungrammatical (unless there's some context which establishes two players, one of them skilled, the other unskilled, so that "the skilled player" refers to *one* of them)</sup>

Comment: then my first sentence is wrong? Does it need a comma before (having)  - Paceman Rubel Hossain was also recalled to the side
after an injury-plagued season, as was left-arm spinner
Taijul Islam, having last played an ODI against New
Zealand in the World Cup last year.

Comment: please ans this.